# Custom SCSS file is not importing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm working on a rails app and using Sass. So far everything has been done in the application.scss file which has worked great.

I'm having two issues which I think are caused by the same problem.

1) I created a users model which generated a users.scss file. When I started to use it, I noticed that it wasn't actually importing into the final web page. So at the top of the application.scss file I added @import "users". Which leads to issue 2.

2) When running the final page, I get a Syntax error: 
Invalid CSS after "// VARIABLES": expected selector or at-rule, was "$hero-font: Lor..."

I'm wondering if I might have missed where the import is happening for the Sass files or am using them incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: did you remove the `*= require` statements from `application.scss`?

Comment: Yup! That's exactlly what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added back the *= require statements from the application.scss file.